# Nginx+Gunicorn+Django1.5 - connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream

Tags: django, configuration, nginx, gunicorn, http-error

I'm getting this when accessing my domain: I'm seeing my default, http500 error django template being displayed.

I have **gunicorn** setup:

```
command = '/usr/local/bin/gunicorn'
logfile = "/home/ubuntu/virtualenv/myapp/error/gunicorn.log"
loglevel = "info"
pythonpath = '/home/ubuntu/virtualenv/myapp'
bind = '127.0.0.1:8001'
workers = 3
```

I have **nginx** config:

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name *.myapp.com;
        access_log /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/myapp/error/access.log;
        error_log /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/myapp/error/error.log warn;
        connection_pool_size 2048;

        fastcgi_buffer_size 4K;
        fastcgi_buffers 64 4k;

        root /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/myapp/homelaunch/;

        location /static/ {
            alias /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/myapp/homelaunch/static/;
            #alias /static/;
            #root /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/myapp/homelaunch/;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            #proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
        }
    }
```

**settings.py**

```
#### LOCAL ENV
#DEBUG = True
#TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

#### PRODUCTION ENV
DEBUG = False
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = False

ADMINS = (
        ('xxx', 'xxx@gmail.com'),
    #('xxx', 'joe@myapp.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'launch',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxx',
        'HOST': '',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default.
    }
}

# Hosts/domain names that are valid for this site; required if DEBUG is False
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['myapp.com','zzz.zz.zzz.zzz','ec2-zz-zz-zz-zz.compute-1.amazonaws.com']
#### MODIFY THIS ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ WHEN USING IN PRODUCTION - DJANGO 1.5.
######## if this is left blank in production, it will not load.

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# In a Windows environment this must be set to your system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/var/www/example.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = ''

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://example.com/media/", "http://media.example.com/"
MEDIA_URL = ''

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/var/www/example.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/ubuntu/virtualenv/myapp/homelaunch/static/'
#STATIC_ROOT = '/static/'
# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://example.com/static/", "http://static.example.com/"
#STATIC_URL = '/home/ubuntu/virtualenv/myapp/homelaunch/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    #'/home/ubuntu/virtualenv/myapp/homelaunch/static/',
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myapp.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myapp.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    '/home/ubuntu/virtualenv/myapp/homelaunch/templates',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'south',
    'homelaunch',
    'gunicorn',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # 'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error when DEBUG=False.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

in **error_log** of this nginx I see:

```
2013/10/25 00:31:49 [error] 1840#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xx.xxx.xx.xxx, server: myapp.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8001/", host: "myapp.com"
```

in **access_log** of this nginx config i see:

```
xx.xxx.xx.xxx - - [25/Oct/2013:00:31:49 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 173 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0"
```

I already tried to read into the problem and saw adding:

```
  fastcgi_buffer_size 4K;
    fastcgi_buffers 64 4k;
```

to the nginx config may help this, but it didn't.

I'm a bit confused on how I can debug this from here? Can someone help?

Thank you.

Comment: The error_log message and access_log message are 10+ minutes apart, and likely unrelated.

Comment: Please review again. Updated.

Comment: Is gunicorn running? Can you connect to it by typing `nc 127.0.0.1 8001`?

Comment: When I run: nc 127.0.0.1:8001 I'm getting: 
This is nc from the netcat-openbsd package. An alternative nc is available
in the netcat-traditional package.

Comment: When I run: nc 127.0.0.1 8001 (different than above) I'm getting nothing in return

Comment: Anything in the gunicorn logs?

Comment: No, they havent been written to in over 2 weeks and have permissions of : rwxrwxrwx , The same as access.log and error.log which have been written to

Comment: If I run: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn -c /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/gunicorn_config.py myapp.wsgi it runs gunicorn fine too

Comment: If I run sudo nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf (to start nginx) it says: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use) . Any ideas?

Comment: I'm a little confused. You said that your django500 is being shown, which means it's able to pass to django successfully and that django is throwing the 500. Can you try curling yourself on that machine and do you get a response? curl http://127.0.0.1:8001

Comment: also, is debug set to false and your "ALLOWED_HOSTS" set correctly in your settings?

Comment: When I curl curl 127.0.0.1:8001 - I get the same output if I view in the browser.

Comment: ALLOWED_HOSTS contains myapp.com in it only..

Comment: I added my settings.py file above - i dont see anything particularly wrong with it though. Thoughts anyone?

Comment: One thing has stayed consistent throughout, 'access.log' has always had entries to it like: xx.xx.xx.xxx - - [25/Oct/2013:11:29:37 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 460 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0" .

Comment: If I setup DEBUG=True and TEMPLATE_DEBUG=True, my app loads fine. But if I set both values to False and the recycle nginx/gunicorn it throws an http500 error .... any thoughts?

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue? Because Im having the same now.. :(

Answer (score 5):

Change your `settings.py` file so that `ALLOWED_HOSTS=['domain']` (or `['*']` to get it working)